# Django Admin Page broken links

Tags: python, django, django-admin, uwsgi, django-wsgi

I am deploying a Django app using uwsgi.
The app is deployed under `SERVER_URL:PORT`.

Using a proxy server, the app can be accessed also via `EXTERNAL_WEB_SITE/MY_APP_NAME`.

When using the admin page, under: `EXTERNAL_WEB_SITE/MY_APP_NAME/ADMIN/`, I can see the correct models. But, the links in the admin page that direct to the models themselves direct to: `EXTERNAL_WEB_SITE/ADMIN/MAIN_PACKAGE/SELECTED_MODEL/`. That is - the MY_APP_NAME won't pass in the link provided.
I suppose this is because in the server itself the app is deployed with no app name, just under a specific port.

In order to solve it, I tried defining `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME=MY_APP_NAME` in `settings.py`. This gives me good links. BUT - when trying to modify an object and save it - under `EXTERNAL_WEB_SITE/MY_APP_NAME/ADMIN/MAIN_PACKAGE/SELECTED_MODEL/ITEM/` - after hitting `Save` I am linked to `EXTERNAL_WEB_SITE/MY_APP_NAME/MY_APP_NAME/ADMIN/MAIN_PACKAGE/SELECTED_MODEL/ITEM/` - that is - I get MY_APP_NAME twice.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass `SCRIPT_NAME` env variable with your request from proxy server

alternatively you could have two instances running one with `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` set and second without

uwsgi have a nice option, that you can deploy your app on two ports or (even better) set env variable depending on headers or paths

```
[uwsgi]
route = ^(/MY_APP_NAME)/ addvar:SCRIPT_NAME=$1
```